# Use reverse geocoding to get city name and state

Tags: javascript, reverse-geocoding, geocode, weather-api

Help! I am new to coding and I just got to the challenge on Free Code Camp where I need to create a website that shows the local weather using reverse geocoding.  I want the page to display the city and state that the user is in.  Right now I have the longitude and latitude, but I don't know how to turn that into city and state. Here is what I have so far.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    $("#city").html("latitude: " + lat +"<br>longitude: " + long);
  });
};
```

I also found this answer on another Stack Overflow question, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that to get the city and state to automatically show up.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
  latitude = 28.54, //sub in your latitude
  longitude = -81.39, //sub in your longitude
  postal_code,
  city,
  state;
geocoder.geocode({ location: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude } }, function(
  results,
 status
) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    results.forEach(function(element) {
      element.address_components.forEach(function(element2) {
        element2.types.forEach(function(element3) {
          switch (element3) {
            case "postal_code":
              postal_code = element2.long_name;
              break;
            case "administrative_area_level_1":
              state = element2.long_name;
              break;
            case "locality":
              city = element2.long_name;
              break;
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What API are you using to get the weather data? They probably return JSON that contains the city and state.

Comment: Google Maps API

Comment: You are getting the weather data from Google Maps?

Comment: I was trying to use Google Maps API to get the city and state.  I actually worked on it a lot today.  I used this API from Free Code Camp (https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude) and it has weather info as well as city and country (not state tho), so I'm just going to go ahead and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I worked on it a lot today and came up with an answer that worked. I knew there had to be a more simple solution than the other solutions I'd been finding out there. I used Free Code Camp's API that they included with the challenge.

```
function getLocation () {
  $.getJSON(('https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=' + latitude + 
'&lon=' + longitude), function(loc) {
$("#city").html(loc.name + ", " + loc.sys.country);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was looking for something similar and am trying https://plus.codes/

If you strip the encoded bit it yields a fairly consistent city, state, country name:

```
const extractCityName = latlng => {
  googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({ latlng }, (err, response) => {
    if (!err) {
      return response.json.plus_code.compound_code.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    }
  });
};


// examples: 

console.log(extractCityName(40.6599718,-73.9817292));
// New York, NY, USA

console.log(extractCityName(37.386052, -122.083851));
// Mountain View, CA, USA

console.log(extractCityName(51.507351, -0.127758));
// Westminster, London, UK
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hit that point, locate the longitude and latitude you already know.

If you want to obtain the corresponding state based on the known longitude and latitude, then you need to know the latitude and longitude range of each state, and then use this range to determine.The same is true of the method of obtaining a city.